# I'm failing to understand Aurelia architecture

Tags: javascript, architecture, frameworks, aurelia

I was hoping someone could shed some light on the Aurelia framework for me. I've noticed many posts out there promoting this framework so I've decided to take a deep dive into it. Though I've had some issues right off the bat with getting starting while reading through their Doc HUB. I see many subjective claims and not very much code. Or diagrams for that matter. Sorry, I might be the visual learner but I think by having something that is "tangible" (as much as the Web could allow) would help people like me adopt this framework.

Now architecture patterns! 
Taken from Aurelia Docs: "MV* with Conventions" or use "jQuery, React, Polymer, Bootstrap, MaterializeCSS and much more."

MVVM or MCV? Well why not MV*! 
Forgive me, but I don't consider Bootstrap a framework in this sense of the word. How would I just use Aurelia? Do I get to decide what architecture I want to use and not pick or piecemeal several ones together? Why is the star there? Is this just me over thinking this or should it be as MV(C | *)?

Also, I've yet to actually write any code using Aurelia and so this question may be easily answered by just trying to use it. I would truly like to see more code out there for this framework. Maybe that would ease my visual brain sponge monster.

Thank you to whomever response to this silly question of which could have easily been answered if I had friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some answers based on my opinion.

> Why is the star there?

The * means "whatever". It could be MVVM, MVC, etc.

> [...] I don't consider Bootstrap a framework in this sense of the word.

Yes, you are right. In fact, jQuery, React and Bootstrap are not really frameworks, but some say that Bootstrap is a "Visual Framework" or "Design Framework". The problem is that the term "framework" is a little vague and could be easily confused.

What the docs wanted to say is that you can use Aurelia with any other libraries that you like. You are not limited to anything.

About the patterns, I think you should see these resources:

Contact Manager Tutorial http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/contact-manager-tutorial/1

A list of apps written with Aurelia (Source-Code Available) http://builtwithaurelia.com/

Official Chat - https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss - This one is the most helpful for you. You can talk to a lot of people and ask many questions as you want. I believe all of your doubts will be answered there.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Although I fully understand what a * means, I was merely poking fun of the loose verbiage noted in the documentation. I feel that it means Aurelia will have unstated dependencies and would divide the community on a standard/prefered practice. What if I just wanted to use "Vanilla" Aurelia and not use jQuery?

Comment: You don't need jQuery, unless if you want to use some library that is dependant from jQuer. I use "vanilla" all the time, and I try to avoid jQuery as much as possible

Comment: spoken like a true developer! Thank you. I feel like you answered most of my questions but I'm still perplexed. Marking as the answer but I will take this question to the Gitter community